# Python Scrapy Function that does always work

Tags: python, scrapy

The script below work 90% of the time to collect weather data. However, there are few cases where for some reason it just fails and the html code is consistant with the other request. There times where code is the same with the same request but it fails.

```
class NflweatherdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'NFLWeatherData'
allowed_domains = ['nflweather.com']
# start_urls = ['http://nflweather.com/']

def __init__(self, Week='', Year='', Game='', **kwargs):
    self.start_urls = [f'https://nflweather.com/{Week}/{Year}/{Game}']  # py36
    self.Year = Year
    self.Game = Game
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    print(self.start_urls)  # python3

def parse(self, response):
    self.log(self.start_urls)
    #self.log(self.Year)
    # pass
    # Extracting the content using css selectors
    # Extracting the content using css selectors
    game_boxes = response.css('div.game-box')

    for game_box in game_boxes:
        # Extracting date and time information
        Datetimes = game_box.css('.col-12 .fw-bold::text').get()

        # Extracting team information
        team_game_boxes = game_box.css('.team-game-box')
        awayTeams = team_game_boxes.css('.fw-bold::text').get()
        homeTeams = team_game_boxes.css('.fw-bold.ms-1::text').get()
        # Extracting temperature and probability information
        TempProbs = game_box.css('.col-md-4 .mx-2 span::text').get()

        # Extracting wind speed information
        windspeeds = game_box.css('.icon-weather + span::text').get()
        winddirection = game_box.css('.md-18 ::text').get()
        # Create a dictionary to store the scraped info
        scraped_info = {
            'Year': self.Year,
            'Game': self.Game,
            'Datetime': Datetimes.strip(),
            'awayTeam': awayTeams,
            'homeTeam': homeTeams,
            'TempProb': TempProbs,
            'windspeeds': windspeeds.strip(),
            'winddirection': winddirection.strip()
        }

        # Yield or give the scraped info to Scrapy
        yield scraped_info
```

These are the scrapy commands to run the crawler

```
scrapy crawl NFLWeatherData -a Week=week -a Year=2012 -a Game=week-6 -o NFLWeather_2012_week_6.json   
scrapy crawl NFLWeatherData -a Week=week -a Year=2012 -a Game=week-7 -o NFLWeather_2012_week_7.json
scrapy crawl NFLWeatherData -a Week=week -a Year=2012 -a Game=week-8 -o NFLWeather_2012_week_8.json
```

Week 6 crawl works perfect no issues

Week 7 Crawl returns nothing

```
ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://nflweather.com/week/2012/week-7> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\MiniConda3\envs\WrkEnv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 279, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
```

Week 8 retrives 2 lines and errors out fro the rest

```
ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://nflweather.com/week/2012/week-8> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\ProgramFiles\MiniConda3\envs\WrkEnv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 279, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
```

Any idea why these files fails and the other files have no issues?

Comment: All weeks produce an error for me, it's just sooner or later for different weeks. You need to fix your code so that the error doesn't happen. For that, apparently, you need to learn how to read the error as you didn't even copy it here.

Comment: The error is very clearly listed above if you got a different error then I cant comment on what your doing. It would have been a nice gesture to at least put your error here to see what it may be.

Comment: It's not the error, it's the first line of it, and it's totally useless. You need to look at the last lines of a Python traceback, not just at the first line of it.

Comment: I still dont see the error your referring to. I see a warning but not an error. If you are seeing a different error than what I have placed go ahead an place your error here. If I knew what the error is I may not be posting a question here.

Comment: Sure, the actual error you are getting is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'".

Comment: @wRAR ok i am new to scrapy and error was not immediately obvious I will not look to resolving that particular error.

Comment: (This is not specific to Scrapy, that's how all Python exception tracebacks look like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies with the `windspeeds` variable, sometimes the weather data is missing and so the `windspeeds` variable will be `None`, then when you attempt to create the dictionary object you envoke `windspeeds.strip()` which throws the exception.

You could solve this by doing a simple `None` check when creating the dictionary, or you're free to do the check earlier, however fits your needs best. But here is a working example

```py
scraped_info = {
   'Year': self.Year,
   'Game': self.Game,
   'Datetime': Datetimes.strip(),
   'awayTeam': awayTeams,
   'homeTeam': homeTeams,
   'TempProb': TempProbs,
   'windspeeds': windspeeds.strip() if windspeeds is not None else "TBD",
   'winddirection': winddirection.strip() if winddirection is not None else "TBD"
}
```

You will also notice that "working" example you provided with `week-6` will now contain more results than before